# HTML file not reading Javascript file in script

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have the following issue. I have a HTML file called "GUI.html" and I'm trying to load a function from a Javascript file called "guiScript.js" but its only function is not recognized:

Html file:

```
<body>
    <h1>Selection</h1>
    <script src="guiScript.js"></script>
    <button onclick="obtenerEquipos()">Generar equipos automáticamente</button>
</body>
```

Javascript file:

```
import fs from 'fs'

function obtenerEquipos(){
fs.readFile('equipos.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    
    // Converting Raw Buffer to text
    // data using tostring function.
    console.log(data);
})
```

}

Error log:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: obtenerEquipos is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (GUI.html:7:44)
```

Does it have anything to do with the import? I can't think of anything else really. I've already read files this way before and it worked correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: `fs` is a Node.js module. That is unavailable in browsers.

Comment: "Does it have anything to do with the import?" — Yes, you should get an error message about it in the console as the page loads. (If you don't, then the `src` probably has the wrong URL).